# Re: How to detect and end game when a pygame sprite runs into its tail?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

I created a snake-like game in which the user moves the sprite, and the sprite leaves a trail. If the user runs into the trail he's created, I'd like the game to end, and the player to lose.

One idea I had was to somehow track past positions of the sprite (maybe in a list), and then create an `if` statement that would lead to a game loss (However, I'm was a little unclear on how to do that).

I received an answer to this question that coded for this list:

> "I think you could declare a two dimensional list like this:
>   `pastPositions = [[400, 300]]`
>   Then every time the player's position moves, check the list:
>   for row in pastPositions:
>   `If (player.rect.x == pastPositions[row][0] and player.rect.y == pastPositions[row][1]): done = true    # game over`
>   If the player hasn't been there yet, then add that position to the list.
>   `pastPositions.append([player.rect.x, player.rect.y])`

This looks like it should work, but when I try to run the code (in Python Interactive), I get an error message that reads: `"line 86, in <module> if player.rect.x == astPositions[row][0] and player.rect.y == pastPositions[row][1]: IndexError: list index out of range"`

What would you suggest I change the range to so that this doesn't happen? I tried setting it to the width and height of the pygame window.

```
import pygame

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

   def __init__(self, x, y):
       super().__init__()

       self.image = pygame.Surface([15, 15])
       self.image.fill(WHITE)

       self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
       self.rect.x = x
       self.rect.y = y

       self.change_x = 0
       self.change_y = 0


   def changespeed(self, x, y):
       self.change_x += x
       self.change_y += y


   def update(self):
       self.rect.x += self.change_x
       self.rect.y += self.change_y

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([800, 600])

pygame.display.set_caption('The Etch-a-Sketch Game')

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Times', 20)
textsurface = myfont.render('This is the Etch-a-Sketch Game', False, (255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(textsurface,(0,0))

myfont = pygame.font.SysFont('Times', 15)
textsurface = myfont.render('Feel free to draw, but if you cross your own    path, you will die.', False, (255, 255, 255))
screen.blit(textsurface,(0,20))


player = Player(400, 300)
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
all_sprites_list.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-3, 0)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0, 3)
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0, -3)

    player.update()

    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(75)

pygame.quit ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Recording the points of a very long path seems like a slow way of checking for hitting one's own tail.

If the background is a known colour, perhaps checking for non-background pixel colours in the area the player is about to move into.

It's possible to grab a single pixel colour with the [Surface.get_at()](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.get_at) function.  This returns a RGBA colour, this colour can be compared against a single background colour (or the known background colour from a bitmap at that point), allowing collision to be decided.

In the `player.update()`:

```
if (screen.get_at((player_next_x, player_next_y)) != BACKGROUND_COLOUR):
    # player hit tail
```

Of course it may be necessary to check both corners of the player's sprite (in the direction of travel).

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It sees like it will work, but I have a couple questions:

Comment: #1 - How do you define the (player_next_x) and (player_next_y), when taking into account the user's input on the direction keys?

Comment: #2 - I ask because I tried this just using (player.rect.x) and (player.rect.y), which I had already defined, and of course the system closed immediately because it detected a "collision" with its current position.

Comment: When the code is about to draw the next player position, it's using these co-ordinates.  So just check before painting on the bitmap.